# Is there a way to force YouTube not to show me videos I've already watched?

Tags: youtube

I'm comfortable with Tampermonkey scripts and writing my own JavaScript, I just can't reasonably comprehend YouTube's generated HTML structure and constant changes enough to know how to write this myself.

What I want is essentially something I can turn on or off that will completely hide videos I've already seen from the suggestions page, the recommended sidebar next to videos and just generally the homepage/the site. It's not that I don't like seeing videos again, it's just the complete burial of suggestions from YouTube of videos I haven't seen among ones I have.

Comment: Does it show you a red bar on the bottom or under video's thumbnails, showing how much of the video you've watched? Not sure if that's standard or from an add-on, but looking for the red bar would be a sign you've seen the video... still see it listed though, but using the "red bar" code could "show what to hide"

Comment: It does show that, and I do use it to indicate if I've watched a video, though my problem is that YouTube almost exclusively recommends videos I've watched, not that I can't tell which are which.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decent script that'll do just what you asked:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/13040-youtube-hide-watched-videos

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes YouTube recommends the videos according to your watch history.
Try deleting your YouTube history.
I have tried this and it mostly suggests me new content.